# Why sometimes order of return value by a function varies in python?

Tags: python

I wrote a simple function to retrieve three outputs from a string. When I want to use the returned value in other functions the order changes. 
For example:

```
def parsetrack2(trackstr):

    cardnumber, date = trackstr.split('=')
    expiryyear = date[0:2]
    expirymonth = date[2:4]

    return{cardnumber,expiryyear,expirymonth}
```

When I want to pass the `cardnumber` and `expiryyear` to another function, sometimes order changes and other times it is right? Why is that?

How should I change it to prevent that variation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because you are returning a dictionaire instead of a list / tuple. (dicts do not save the order of the elements, while lists / tuples does)

Just change the :

```
return{cardnumber,epxiryyear,epxirymonth}
```

to:

```
return(cardnumber,epxiryyear,epxirymonth)
```

Then the result order will remain the same.

Comment: Actually, you are returning a set, which also does not have order.

Comment: It's not a `dict`, it's a `set`. Also, typically, when returning multiple values, I typically don't bother with parens at all; I use parens when I'm making a data structure, but in this case, the fact that Python implements multiple return values as a `tuple` is irrelevant (the caller should be unpacking them anyway), so I'd just go with `return cardnumber, epxiryyear, epxirymonth`

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
{item_1, item_2, ...}
```

is actually a set literal (not a dict). A set is an unordered collection of items with no repeats. Therefore, the order of the items returned is random. Instead do this

```
def func():
    return 1, 2, 3

>>> a, b, c = func()
>>> a
1
>>> b
2
>>> c
3
```